# python3.5 open file with latin1 character on name

Tags: python-3.x, directory, pathlib

I have a file called "não.mp3", when I try to open it with pathlib, the name is converted to "nao.mp3", since there is no such file in the folder, python returns an error:

```
>>> p = Path("D:/não.mp3")
>>> p
WindowsPath('D:/nao.mp3')
>>> p.exists()
False
>>> with p.open() as f: f.readline()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\everton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\pathlib.py", line 1136, in open
    opener=self._opener)
  File "C:\Users\everton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\pathlib.py", line 992, in _opener
    return self._accessor.open(self, flags, mode)
  File "C:\Users\everton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\pathlib.py", line 371, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\nao.mp3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like you're going to have to pass the Unicode code-point as part of your string. The code-point for ã is '00E3' Try this:

```
p = Path("D:/n\u00e3o.mp3")
```

When doing this on Windows 10 (and having a corresponding file), I get

```
>>> p.exists()
True
```

It doesn't look like pathlib handles unicode characters in the way you expect. You could try another library, like `os` or `shutil`.

`os.listdir` can give you all of the filenames in a directory if you give it the directory name as a bytes `b''`:

```
>>> os.listdir(b'D:/')
[b'n\xe3o.mp3']
```

Using this, you can get a list of all your files that you can use to build paths. You can convert the bytes object back to a string by using `bytes_object.decode('latin-1')`

Comment: So, is there a way for me to take the list a = ["não", "ã"] and automatically pass the code-points into the list, so the results would be a = ["n\u00e3o", "\u00e3"]?

Comment: Could try using the `str.replace('a', '\u00e3')` method in a loop.

Comment: I think it would not work, if I had an word like "and" in the list it would become "\u00e3nd" :( I'm trying to figure out how to handle it in general, for any word.

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to get a list of filenames as bytes. Does that help? You can then do `filename.decode('latin-1')` on each filename you get.

Comment: The problem is that if you just enter `'ã'` into your source code, python will change it to `'a'`. You may be able to fix this by putting `# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-` at the top of your source file.